# Snowflake - Check string is alpha numeric or not?

Tags: sql, regex, string, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column that should not contain any alphanumeric value. I have tried

```sql
case when col1 like '%[0-9]%' 
    then 1 
    else 0 
end
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`like` does not understand the pattern that you are giving it. You want a regex match, so use a regex function:

```
select col1, regexp_like(col1, '.*[0-9].*') has_number from mytable
```

This gives you a boolean value (`true` / `false`). If you want a number, you can `cast` or use a `case` expression instead.

This checks if the string contains *any number*. If you want to search for
*any alphanumeric* character, then `\w` comes handy:

```
regexp_like(col1, '.*\\w.*')
```

And finally if you want to ensure that the string contains *only alphanumeric* characters:

```
regexp_like(col1, '^\\w*$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement doesn't work because you need to use a regexp keyword to use regexps, and your regexp is wrong.

```sql
select ...
from   ...
where
  lower(field) regexp '[a-z0-9]+'
```

See the regexp documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
select regexp_like(lower(my_str), '[a-z0-9]+')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.